# ggplot2 put >= (one character) in sprintf() for panel legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to put some additional information, e.g. numbers and fractions, into a panel legend for my plots, and I would like to provide the count of rows where a value is >= some threshold.  My legend is made using `sprintf("N=%d fn=%.3f ...",var1,var2,...)`.

How can I put a ">=" (as one character perhaps by using expression()) into the legend labels where some of the parts are made with sprintf()? (I am printing a PDF for a manuscript, so using \u2265 does not work.)

I can imagine I need to use expression on a string that contains ">=", but it is unclear where to do that.

Comment: I usually google ">= sign" (or something like that) to find a webpage that has it and copy/paste `≥` into my R code.

Comment: E.g., `ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + geom_point() + labs(x = 'This ≥ is here')`

Comment: @GregorThomas isn't that equivalent to \u2265?

Comment: Hmmm, I suppose so. Not sure why it wouldn't work when printing a PDF for a manuscript. Perhaps more context is needed - a minimal reproducible example would help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Bottom line, I was unable to render '≥' on MacOS without the 'Cairo' device package.  If you have that package (which on MacOS also requires Xquartz, for no apparent reason), then you can use the unicode character \u2265, or copy/paste '≥', or use element_markdown() with "≥".

Without 'Cairo', none of the suggestions work with the default PDF device in 'R'. On MacOS, '...' is output in the PDF file, presumably because '≥' is not represented by the default fonts.  'Cairo' provides '≥' (and many other characters).